# .htaccess hiding specific folder

Tags: .htaccess

If I want to hide a specific subfolder for certain files, I can use the following
RewriteEngine On

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+folder/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^folder/)^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will make from **www.site/folder/file1.php** >> **www.site/file1.php**

But if I place this in my root folder, this affects files in other directories. For example, for www.site/index.php the folder will be invisibly added to the URL.

I tried to create an .htacces file inside specific 'folder' folder but it still seems to affect for example my index.php file.

My file structure is as follows:

- index.php
- folder

  -file1.php

  -file2.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you are saying that `www.example.com/index.php` is also not working after these rules?

Comment: correct this returns an error 404. Only if I go directly to for example www.example.com/folder/file.php it works. And then the result is as expected correct (www.example.com/file.php).

(I have the feeling that `RewriteRule (?!^folder/)^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]` also affects the index file in my rootfolder.